# Clearing a specific environment in R

Tags: r

I have got the following environment in R:

```
ee = new.env()
ee$a = 1
ee$b = 3
ee$z = 5
```

Clearing specific variables works as expected:

```
rm("z", envir=ee)
ls(ee)
# "a", "b"
```

But why is clearing all variables not working?

```
rm(ls(ee), envir=ee)
# Error in rm(ls(ee), envir = ee) : 
#  ... must contain names or character strings
```

Comment: `rm(list=ls(ee),envir=ee)` first arg of rm is a name, if you wish to pass it a vector you must use `list=`

Comment: Err, of course. Please post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: Didn't see that, you can close it.

Comment: No problem :) The duplicate feature of SO is there for that.